# Select Array types in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra

I have this table in cassandra DB where one of the column holds list of ip address like {['[10.100.164.33]', '[10.100.164.36]', '[10.100.164.37]'}. 
Now i want to query through spark sql like select the row where one of the ip is 10.100.164.36. How to query that in spark sql.

Table has 3 fields current_time, destinationips and source_ip

the output should be

```
 1495448344501 | {'[10.100.1.25]', '[10.100.164.36]'} |   192.168.11.1
```

could anyone please help

Comment: what have you tried? also your expected output is inconsistent with the data you shared.

Comment: Are you interested in `destinationips` only?

Answer (score 0):

After you create a dataframe, reading a casandra DB and get a list in a destinationip field, you can query like this

```
  val spark =
    SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("test").getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  val data = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
    (123, Array("10.100.1.25", "10.100.164.36"), "10.100.164.32"),
    (456, Array("10.100.1.25", "10.100.164.3"), "10.100.164.32"),
    (45, Array("10.100.1.25", "10.100.164.36"), "10.100.164.32"),
    (46, Array("10.100.1.25", "10.100.164.367"), "10.100.164.32")
  )).toDF("current_time","destinationips", "source_ip")


  data.select("*").where(array_contains(data("destinationips"), "10.100.164.36")).show
```

Comment: i tried this query

but it is giving error Undefined function: 'data'.This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.; line 1 pos 60"

Comment: data is a dataframe in your case realace the data variable with your dataframe name.